# A style change function reloads the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, browser

In my webpage, i have this code :

```
    function closesearch() {
  document.getElementById("searchbar").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("triggerbar").style.display = "block";
```

This actually closes a search box which is open. But whenever i click the close button, the whole webpage reloads, which is unnecessary.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: There's definitely more happening than what you've posted here

Comment: Is your close button inside a form?

Comment: I'm guessing your button is of `type='submit'` and is in a form. A simple solution is to set it to `type='button'`.

Comment: Yes. Its inside a form and its trying to close the same form. The form is given the id "searchbar" and button is inside the form.

Comment: please post your html code

Comment: You were right. It's was caused because the button was placed inside a form. Now i changed its type and problem solved. Thank you!!